# Is there a way to add TOC to sig-alternate?

Tags: table-of-contents, document-classes, tex4ht

Is there any possible way to add toc to sig-alternate? Otherwise i would need to rework my whole documentary.
Sig-alternate is a type of acm document, like article

Comment: and what is `sig-alternate`? You probably need to provide more information avout what exactly you are doing

Comment: @daleif It is part of `tex4ht` I think.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example of the code you're using? Something which begins `\documentclass` and ends `\end{document}` with a few sections or whatever you want in the ToC.

Comment: @cfr there is an old configuration file for `six-alternate` in TeX4ht, but I don't know anything about it. I guess someone requested it for their custom class that was never published on CTAN, while the config file is, as it is included in TeX4ht distro.